# How can I identify the node that causes package loss?

Tags: networking, internet

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask but I am having the problem that my internet connection drops packages from time to time. This causes TCP connection problems while gaming or sometimes causes problems while I stream something.

I am sure that the problem is not on my side but I want to have something in my hands before I call the customer service.

How could I track down e.g. the node that causes the package loss? I've tried [WinMTR](http://winmtr.net/) but I'm not sure how to interpret the output:

[image]

---

**Q:** "*How many computers are on your network? What kind of Internet connection do you have? Is your router separate from your modem?*"

**A:** *It's just one Computer that is connected to a wireless router which is directly connected to cable (Fiber Power froM UPC, 75 Mbit/s down, 7.5 Mbit/s up).*

---

**Q:** "*What is the result of netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces*"

**A:** I am getting:

```
   MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface
------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
4294967295            1          0     509966  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  1500                1 1022532031   22592325  Wireless Network Connection
  1500                5          0      97088  Wireless Network Connection 2
  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection
  1500                5          0      99712  Wireless Network Connection 3
```

---

Comment: How many computers are on your network?
What kind of Internet connection do you have?
Is your router separate from your modem?

Comment: @pooter03 I've edited my question. :)

Comment: Start off by running  continuous pings to your router and to a public IP address, such as your ISP's DNS server.  When you start to have packet loss, see if is dropping both on your router and the public IP or just to the public IP.

Comment: What is the result of `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces`?

Comment: @pooter03 That is a good idea! I'll start doing it but I'll have to wait because those drops appear very randomly!

Comment: @boboes I've added the information to my question.

Comment: try pingtest.net to somewhere local & also somewhere near the IP you get problems with.

Comment: As a shot in the dark: your [mtu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) may be to high. Try from elevated cmd.exe: `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Wireless Network Connection" mtu=1490  store=persistent`. If nothing changes, try 1480 and if this doesn't help go back to 1500. Google for `find optimum mtu size`

Answer (score 0):

Some basic troubleshooting steps for packetloss:
 1.  Make sure it's not the computer.   Scan for malware, update your network drivers, etc.  Use another computer/tablet/phone and see if you see the same packetloss at the same time.  If you can't get another computer, you should be able to find apps that let you ping from your phone or tablet.  As mentioned before, run a continuous ping to your gateway.  If you drop packets and are wireless, try wired and see if it makes a difference.
 2.  If it isn't a computer problem, check your router.  Make sure you are on the latest firmware.  Check to make sure you aren't using a crowded wireless channel if applicable.  Make sure your WiFi is secure and that no one is If you find that power cycling your router solves the issue, consider replacing it if the firmware update didn't help.
 3. Isolate the cable modem by plugging your computer directly to the cable modem making sure no other network device has a connection.  If you find packetloss still, try to replicate the issue from two or more different computers.  That way if your ISP blames your equipment, you can let them know it happened on multiple machines.